# Include template on button click

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying a list of items as follows:

```
<ul data-ng-controller="TodoController">
  <li data-ng-repeat="todo in model.todos">
    {{todo.id}} : {{todo.name}}
    <a href="#">Edit</a>
    <a href="#">Show</a>
  <li>
</ul>
```

And then I have two templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
  Edit template
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="show">
  Show template
</script>
```

How can I show each template when the button edit or show is clicked?
And how can I "pass" the data from that row to the template?

I was looking to use ng-include as I am not using routing.

Comment: ng-include and ng-if do not work? To "pass" variables you can just define in $scope variable with same names as used in template.

Comment: Yes, I want to use ng-include ... But can you give me an example of the proper way to do it? And can I use a different controller for each of the templates? So repeat would use TodoListController, edit would use TodoEditController and show would use TodoShowController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite straightforward:

```
<div ng-include="'edit'" ng-if="..." ></div>
<div ng-include="'show'" ng-if="..." ></div>
```

To have controllers in templates, just add them:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="show">
  <div ng-controller="c2">Show template {{obj}}
  </div>

</script>
```

Small plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HgiT61ODZ7uAgq4rGpA5?p=preview

Comment: I found what was my error ... I didn't have ' ' around the name in ng-include. One question: when I click the Edit button I need to "pass" that item data to the c2 controller. Can I do this?

Comment: you can just access parent scope